# Error in connecting to Salesforce with correct credentials

Tags: login

Everytime I want to logged in to Salesforce (sandbox) I have this error :
"**Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator.**"

I checked the username, password and the instance of Salesforce everything is OK.
To logged in I ask for an another user to reset my password.

Somebody had like this problem, and how he fixed it? Should I open a case to Salesforce?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you accessing the sandbox from test.salesforce.com? Also, are you logging in with yourname@yourcompany.com.sandboxname?

Comment: Yes I tried this also, but the problem is because I putted a wrong username. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I putted a username not correct. I didn't pay attention that the username is changed after my last refresh.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58217)

Comment: Yes, I answered myself. But I will check the answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Logins to sandboxes must be made on https://test.salesforce.com or from the custom domain URL of the sandbox. Also, depending on the org configuration, you can ONLY login from the domain page.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your fast reply, I found finally the problem.I refreshed the sandbox and I did not pay attention that the username is changed.